# convert javascript array from php variable

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a script with Ajax request.
I get the following array from a php variable.
This array is used in the script

prova.php

```
<?php $x='{x:"0.7129415111913572", y:"0.4862778730703259", note:"a", type:"2", id:"2"},{x:"0.27190696187655316", y:"0.7572898799313894", note:"b", type:"2", id:"3"}'; ?>
<textarea name="update2" id="update2"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($x); ?></textarea>
```

index.php

```
$.ajax({    
    type: "GET",
    url: "/admin/include/data/prova.php?id="+datastr_data,
    data: datastr_data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("#data-result_map").html(html);
```

```
        var notes2=[$('#update2').val()]; // NOT WORKS (alert produces a result of the string)
        var notes2=[<?php echo $xxxx ?>]; //WORKS (alert produces [object, Object],[object, Object]

        $img.imgNotes("import",notes2);                           

    },async: false

});
```

The same content created by an internal variable works and is converted into object, while the step from the outside remains a variable and does not work.

Comment: why not simply return a json data from your php side then append it to your html textarea?

Answer (score 0):

Return a json object from your PHP.

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

You can use JSON.parse to manipulate the result in **success** function in your JS.

```
var result = JSON.parse(html);
```